# Python string manipulation, remove content by finding closing bracket to opening bracket

Tags: python, string

The question is to remove the contents from opening brackets '[' to closing brackets ']'
I managed to write it out, but I am failing certain test cases given to me as the output is not what the question wanted.

A tip I was given is, first find the premier closing bracket']' then trace back to the latest opening bracket '[' and remove all the contents starting from the premier closing bracket to the latest opening bracket.
But, I have no idea how to write it out. Any help is appreciated thank you

My code is as followed:

```
def trial():
    b = False
    user_input = input("test cases : ")
    formatstr = ""
    for i in user_input:
        if '[' in i:
            b = True
        elif not b:
            formatstr += i
        if ']' in i:
            b = False
     print(formatstr)
 trial()
```

These are the test cases with the desired output.

Followed by my output which fails some of the test cases

```
[[bean]abc  → [abc  
**My Output = abc**  `Testcase failed`    
    
 [bean]]abc → ]abc  
**My Ouput = ]abc** `Testcase passed`
    
 abc[foo][qwerty] → abc  
**My Output = abc** `Testcase passed`
    
 abc[qwerty]bean] → abcbean]  
**My Output = abcbean]** `Testcase passed`
 
  abc[qwerty[bean] → abc[qwerty
**My Output = abc**  `Testcase failed`
   
  bean[abc[qwe]dfg] → bean
**My Output = beandfg]**  `Testcase failed`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically deal with nested structures by implementing a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). When you encounter a `"["` you add an item to the stack and when you encounter a `"]"` you `pop()` from the stack. Otherwise you add to the append to the item at the top of the stack. In your examples you need to make sure you add the actual brackets since the tests seem to want them. That might look like:

```
def trial(user_input):
    groups = ['']
    for i in user_input:
        if i == '[':
            groups.append(i)
        elif i == ']' and len(groups) > 1:          
            groups.pop()
        else:
            groups[-1] += i
    return "".join(groups)

assert(trial("[[bean]abc") == "[abc")
assert(trial("[bean]]abc") == "]abc")
assert(trial("abc[foo][qwerty]") == "abc")
assert(trial("abc[qwerty]bean]") == "abcbean]")
assert(trial("abc[qwerty[bean]") == "abc[qwerty")
assert(trial("bean[abc[qwe]dfg]") == "bean")

# all pass
```