# Remove elements in the square bracket of a string from Python

Tags: python, arrays, substring, square-bracket

I am required to remove the elements within the square bracket of a string. However, I am unable to get the desired results.

Below is desired output I am required to get:

**Example of the Output**

[[apple].png -> [.png

[apple]].png -> ].png

[[apple]].png -> [].png

[an]apple[adaykeeps]]the[[doctor]away.png -> apple]the[away.png

Below are the methods I've used but was unable to get the required output:

**Regex Method**

file = re.sub(r'(\d*\D+\d*)\s+','',re.sub(r'{.+?#(\d+).\d+)}',r'(\1)',file));

**SubString Method**

openbracket = file.find('[');
closebracket = file.find(']');

if len(file) > closebracket :
file = file[0: openbracket:] + file[closebracket + 1::]

Comment: Why doesn't `[[apple]].png` -> `.png`?

Comment: removing only the inner most bracket

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64475084/python-string-manipulation-remove-content-by-finding-closing-brackets-to-openin/64475226#64475226) might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with regex; your regex needs to match a `[` followed by some number of non `[` or `]` characters until a `]`, and replace that string with nothing:

```
import re

strings = ['[[apple].png', '[apple]].png', '[[apple]].png', '[an]apple[adaykeeps]]the[[doctor]away.png']

for s in strings:
    name = re.sub(r'\[[^][]*\]', '', s)
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
[.png
].png
[].png
apple]the[away.png
```

This code will replace `[]` with an empty string ``; if this is not the desired behaviour change the `*` in the regex to a `+`.

Comment: Could use `+` or `*` depending on how the input `'[].png'` is supposed to be handled.

Comment: @jez good point, I've made that edit. It seems likely to the correct behaviour. Added a note just in case...

Comment: Today I Learned: that you can put `][` inside `[]` without escaping them (provided they're in that order, I presume). I'm not sure whether it's harder to read with or without escaping...

Comment: @jez yeah, it looks weird and the ordering is all important to make it work. It's a bit of a toss-up as to readability because it does look like a character set of `[^]` followed by another of `[]`...